# Express parse JSON without content-type header

Tags: node.js, json, express, content-type

I have an Express API which is replacing an existing API. The existing API receives JSON data but does not require the content-type header. Express seems to require this header for any parsing of the body into JSON and is returning undefined.

Is there a way to get Express to assume the data is a JSON type without the content-type header set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parseing of request bodies is done using the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) library which has an option to change the [allowed content-type header values](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#type). Here an example that replaces the check with a function that always returns true, thereby always trying to parse the body as json.

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  type(req) {
    return true;
  }
}))
```